# How to get the path of selected file from browse in tkinter python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, directory, project

I am making a game laucnher project, where you can browse through the games and then organise them all at one place.
The issue i am getting is:

To browse i written this code:

```
def browse():
global name
global app_bro
global data
global f
global g
global list_of
app_bro = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='',filetype = [('Application', '*.exe')])

name = os.path.basename(app_bro)

moment=time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d__%H_%M_%S",time.localtime())



f_name = 'C:/Users/vatsa/Desktop/Launcher/mygames/'+name+ '.txt'

with open(f_name, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(name, f)


with open(f_name , 'rb') as f:
    list_of = pickle.load(f)
```

here, this is the part of the code to browse the apps:

```
app_bro = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='',filetype = [('Application', '*.exe')])
```

Now, i want to get the file path of the selected file, and i want to use that path to run the exe app when clicked on a button. here is the code:

```
def open_app():
win_cmd = app_bro
process = subprocess.Popen(win_cmd,
shell=True,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.PIPE )
```

in the win_cmd variable, we are supposed to pass the path of the file to run the application, so i put app_bro variable which earlier used to browse. i am getting the following error:

```
NameError: name 'app_bro' is not defined
```

Comment: How about you pass the variable `app_bro` to the function `open_app`. The `NameError` indicates the python doesn't know about the existance of that variable within it's current scope.

Comment: open_app() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app_bro'   I am getting this error

Comment: Function definition should look like `def open_app(app_bro):` and the call to the function should be something like `open_app(app_bro)`. Didn't think how to pass arguments to a function would need explaining.

Comment: btw You can just do this: `global var1, var2, var3` and so on, don't need to create every new one in a new line

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we need to get rid of the **global** variable since they aren't really useful in this situation. We can use the **return** instead in order to have a code way cleaner and usable in multiple files.

Than, you can execute the file using the **os** module, mostly the script:

```py
os.system(f"start {path}")
```

The final piece of code is:

```py
import os
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
import time

def browse():
    app_bro = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='',filetype = [('Application', '*.exe')])

    name = os.path.basename(app_bro)

    moment=time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d__%H_%M_%S",time.localtime())

    username = os.getenv("UserName")
    path = f"C:\\Users\\{username}\\Downloads\\{name}"

    os.system(f"start {path}")

    return {"app":app_bro, "name":name, "moment":moment, "username":username, "path":path}

browse()
```

Here you go :)